# Android Emulator doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I'm new to Android Development and am currently trying to develop my first application

I started with the tuturial available here: [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html)

I just setup the complete environment for android development:

OS: Windows 7 x64, CPU: 3 GHZ AMD Phenom II X4, RAM: 8GB.
IDE: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Version: Indigo Service Release 1)

I downloaded the SDK from here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
Then i followed the instructions from the tutorial.

However my problem is: When I run the application as an Android Application the emulator gets started, but then get stuck at the following screen:

[image: Emulator Screen]

Even after waiting for more than 30 minutes or even 1 hour it displays still the same screen.

There was only one "problem" while installing the Java JDK:
 - For the JRE was already a newer version installed. (Installed: "Java(TM) 7 Update 2 (64-bit)" I however downloaded the latest sdk from the oracle site. I don't know if the runtime und the sdk must have the same version...

In addition I was yesterday once I able to start the emulator and as long as I let it run it worked quite well... I could even debug the application... However, if I now tried to start the device from eclipse it crashed instantly. Same thing if I start it from de AVD Manager directly ("From Snapshot" or with "Wipe User Data" doesn't matter...). So I deleted the device and created a new one with the same options. Now however I am again stuck at the screen above.

I have no idea of how the whole emulator works. In addition there is A LOT of information in the internet available about crashes and so on (lots of them for earlier releases of the AVD, however I havn't found anything that helped my out.

It would be quite useful to know how the emulator usually works. And maybe getting a hint, what I could do to.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you checked the sdk and eclipse for updates?

Comment: Downloaded and installed them both fresh from the official sites yesterday. Also with "Check for Updates" in eclipse there is nothing to update. JDK is Version 7u1. There is no newer version available

Comment: I had a similar issue when updating from the JDK 6 to 7, and solved it by going back to the JDK 6. I still cannot use the JDK 7 for a mysterious reason.

Comment: I'll try. Do I have to pay attention to something when downgrading to JDK6? (e.g. are there some configurations in eclipse/android sdk) to update?

Comment: Do you get any particular messages where the emulator hangs, when you start the emulator from command line? See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html)

Comment: With the newly created device it starts by calling "emulator -avd GoogleTestDevice" and then stays at the above screen (note: it doesn't crash. it just doesn't display the gui with the apps and so on)

Comment: @LadaRaider it seems to have worked with JDK6u27 :) you can post it as the answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue when updating from the JDK 6 to 7, and solved it by going back to the JDK 6. I still cannot use the JDK 7 for a mysterious reason.